# Find array which has duplicate array

Tags: php, arrays

I have array like below, you can see **71** and **33** are duplicate value so I need find those array which has duplicate values

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 71
            [1] => 33
            [2] => 46
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 71
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 71
            [1] => 33
        )

)
```

Expected output: I want array something like below

```
Array
    (
        [71] => Array
            (
                [0] => 0
                [1] => 1
                [2] => 4
            )

        [33] => Array
            (
                [0] => 0
                [1] => 4
            )

    )
```

Comment: 0,1,4 - what is this?

Comment: these are index of parent array

Comment: parent key value

Comment: Please share your try ?

Comment: @C2486 I have tried many things but not working so post here?

Comment: With such a high rep you're aware that you should show some attempts. I don't see anything here.

Comment: do you know about any loop `for` or `foreach` with some array method `array_search` ?

Comment: you guys have much knowledge then give answer because I'm not much familiar with PHP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could loop over the main array and values to store index a new array. Finally, you could reduce it to keep only duplicates using [`array_filter()`](https://php.net/array_filter):

```
$array = array(
    0 => array(
            0 => 71,
            1 => 33,
            2 => 46
        ),
    1 => array(
            0 => 71
        ),
    4 => array(
            0 => 71,
            1 => 33
        )
);

// loop over the main array:
foreach ($array as $index => $arr_values) {
    // loop over values:
    foreach ($arr_values as $value) {
        $out[$value][] = $index;
    }
}

// finally, remove entries with only one values:
$out = array_filter($out, function($values) { return count($values) > 1 ; });

print_r($out);
```

Outputs:

```
Array
(
    [71] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 4
        )

    [33] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
            [1] => 4
        )
)
```